# Como selecionar todos os id's exceto um?

Tags: sql

Existe alguma maneira de em SQL eu pegar todos os dados exceto um ID?

Por exemplo (eu sei que isto no existe no SQL)

```
Select * From Utilizadores Where id_ut != 1;
```

Comment: Existe sim o diferente `<> ou !=`, tem `not` as vezes acompanhado do `in`, qual banco está usando?

Comment: Eu queria entender o porque que utilizando o != não resolveu o seu problema. Você fez uma pergunta com a solução já...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Além da forma que você já fez na sua pergunta,em que usa o **não igual a** ( != ), pode fazer de outras maneiras:

Usando o **diferente de**:

```
Select * From Utilizadores Where id_ut <> 1;
```

Usando o **not in**:

```
Select * From Utilizadores Where id_ut not in (1); 
/*Usando o not in, você pode passar uma lista de valores (1,2,10)*/
```

---

Lembrando que você pode usar esses 3 operadores ( `<>`, `!=`, `not in` ) não apenas com valores numéricos, mas com textos também.
Por exemplo:

```
Select * From Utilizadores Where nome_ut not in ('João', 'Pedro', 'Maria'); 

Select * From Utilizadores Where nome_ut <> 'João'; 

Select * From Utilizadores Where nome_ut != 'João';
```

Answer (score 1):

Oi, faz assim:

```
Select * From Utilizadores Where id_ut <> 1;
```

Comment: Roger, podes explicar porque essa linha de código resolve o problema? Assim ajuda a perceber o problema e a resposta a quem não sabe o que `<>` significa. Obrigado!